# using a constructor inside a MACRO

Tags: c++, templates, macros, constructor

I came across an error which I can't understand. I have a define in a header file that looks like this:

```
#define ASSERT_THROWS(exception_type,command) do {\
  try { \
    (command); \
    FAIL(std::string("Expected exception of type ") + #exception_type); \
  } catch (AssertionError&) { \
    throw; \
  } catch (exception_type&) { \
    \
  } catch (std::exception& e) { \
    FAIL(std::string("Expected exception of type ") + #exception_type + \
        ", but caught" + e.what()); \
  } catch (...) { \
    FAIL(std::string("Expected exception of type ") + #exception_type + \
        ", but caught an unknown object"); \
  } \
} while (0)
```

and `main` that looks like this:

```
ASSERT_THROWS(TqIllegalGradeException, (TQ<In,Out,TESO<In,Out> > tqS(101)));
```

I get the following errors:
`expected primary-expression before 'tqS'` and `expected ')' before 'tqS'` . can someone explain what is the problem? removing the parenthesis from the macro definition doesn't help

Comment: Look at the preprocessed form of your source file, e.g. file `yoursource.ii` obtained with `g++ -Wall -C -E yoursource.cc > yoursource.ii`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro surrounds its argument with parentheses to form the first statement. This is fine if the argument is an expression (as the name `exp` implies), but not if it's a declaration, since the grammar doesn't allow you to put parentheses around a declaration.

Either remove the parentheses from the macro definition, or don't try to use it for declarations.

Also, if you're hoping that the second line will print the expression itself, rather than the string `"exp"`, then you want to stringify it rather than put it in quotes:

```
std::cout << #exp << std::endl;
```

**UPDATE** In the new code, you've got two sets of parentheses:

```
(command);
^       ^

ASSERT_THROWS(TqIllegalGradeException, (TQ<In,Out,TESO<In,Out> > tqS(101)));    
                                       ^                                 ^
```

both of which will need to be removed if you want to allow `command` to be a declaration. Unfortunately, removing the parentheses from the macro invocation will break the preprocessor, since it doesn't recognise `<>` as brackets; you'll probably need less ambitious macro usage:

```
typedef TQ<In,Out,TESO<In,Out> > Thingy;
ASSERT_THROWS(TqIllegalGradeException, Thingy tqS(101));
```

Finally, if you can't remove the parentheses from the macro, perhaps you could replace the declaration with an expression that constructs a temporary in the same way:

```
ASSERT_THROWS(TqIllegalGradeException, (TQ<In,Out,TESO<In,Out> >(101)));
```

Comment: @littlerunaway: exactly the same, you've just added a load of irrelevant code.

Comment: @littlerunaway: You've also added parentheses to the macro argument `(TQ<...> tsS(101))`, as well as its use in the macro `(command)`. Get rid of both sets of parentheses if you want it to work with a declaration.

Comment: if I remove the parenthesis from (TQ...) I get an error that the MACRO gets 5 arguments instead of 2. it's the only reason I put them there in the first place

Comment: @littlerunaway: see the last paragraph of the answer. I don't think you can force such a complicated declaration through the preprocessor , sorry.

Comment: but even with the `typedef` version, it still won't work with the parenthesis in the MACRO definition, right? (the file with the definition is a given, I can't change it, so I just want to make sure, before I send my instructor an e-mail about the problem)

Comment: @littlerunaway: Yes, whatever you do, you have to remove all the parentheses if you want to allow declarations as well as expressions. If you can't remove the parentheses, you're restricted to expressions.